# I need to click on a td, but selenium reports an error "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element"

Tags: python, html, selenium, html-table

This is the HTML of the page:

```
<td class="titulo_lateral" onclick="javascript: abreMenu(&quot;layer8&quot;);" style="cursor:pointer;">RELATÓRIOS</td>
```

I'm trying this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='f']/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below xpath.

```
//td[@class='titulo_lateral']
```

or

```
//td[text()='RELATÓRIOS' and contains(@onclick,'abreMenu')]
```

but first you will have to make sure that if it is unique in **HTMLDOM** or not.

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

once we have unique matching xpath. you can try to click on it by below methodology.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='RELATÓRIOS' and contains(@onclick,'abreMenu')]").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[text()='RELATÓRIOS' and contains(@onclick,'abreMenu')]"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='RELATÓRIOS' and contains(@onclick,'abreMenu')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='RELATÓRIOS' and contains(@onclick,'abreMenu')]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Hi @Cruisepandey!

None of the codes you sent me worked. I did the xpath lookup in HTMLDOM, and it's unique. The error selenium reports is this: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[text() ='REPORTS' and contains(@onclick,'abreMenu')]"}`

Comment: The text is `RELATÓRIOS` not `REPORTS`, please use this xpath  `//td[text()='RELATÓRIOS' and contains(@onclick,'abreMenu')]`

Comment: The error is as follows: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[text()='RELATÓRIOS' and contains(@onclick,'abreMenu')]"}`

Comment: You need to switch to frame first, get the frame xpath and then put that into `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("frame xpath"))` and then use any of my solution from above

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the `td`, and thus the corresponding XPath, has been rendered on the page when that line of Selenium has executed?

If so, you can try using the full XPath rather than the relative XPath [Copy Full XPath button pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFrGD.png)

Comment: I tried using the full xpath, but it didn't work either.